# overridepending transition slide down animation not working in on finish() for transparent activity

Tags: android, android-animation

I have created a transparent activity with the below theme

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

while launching Transparent activity,I have added slide up animation when calling overridependingtransition after startactivity() call, which works perfectly.

But when I exit the transparent activity i am calling overridepending transition  after finish()  which is not working. The reason why the exit animation is not working is because of the property  `<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>` . If i remove this property exit animation works perfectly but the transparent property of the window is lost.Is there any work around or alternative solution for this please help.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? An activity transition with a shared element?

Comment: Iam trying to show an overlay that covers the entire activity. The overlay is tranparent so that underlying activity should be visible a part of the overlay will display some status message.

Comment: Don't use a transparent `Activity` for that. It will just cause problems. Just show a transparent `View` across the whole screen together with the message you want to display.